# Cannot print the receipt in python3.9, escposprinter library for windows10 platform

Tags: python, receipt, escpos, python-3.9

I am developing hotel billing system that prints the bill receipt using thermal printer but i am stuck at [Errno None] Other errors
python3.9 library: escposprinter & libusb-1.0, plateform:windows 10 Thermal printer: xlab xp-58III

```
from escposprinter import *
try:
    Epson = printer.Usb(0x0416, 0x5011)
    Epson.text('Hello World')
    Epson.cut()
except Exception as e:
    print("PRINTER ERROR: ", e)
```

Result:

> Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform  if i
> remove try block then, Result: Process finished with exit code
> -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

What is the problem?

Comment: The error code seems to be STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN [2.3.1 NTSTATUS Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Look at the Windows event log or check the operation with the debugger. Or if you think the Python version may have an effect, please try 3.8 or 3.7.

Comment: @kunif: this should be the answer

Comment: @sophros : My comment seems to be a hint to investigate the situation and the cause, not the answer to the problem.